# OpenGL the problem of figure rotation (the figure begins to shift)

Tags: opengl

I draw two figures, in this method I rotate only one of them.but applying successive transformations over these two figures, I ran into a rotation problem.I can consistently apply scaling, offset to these figures separately and everything works fine, in the sense that by changing one figure, the previous one retains its previous state. But it doesn't work the same way with rotations. I do the displacement of the figure, and then the rotation of the other, then again the transformation over the first figure, and the second figure that I rotated begins to change its position too, although it should not do this. Tell me, what is the problem?

```
    private void rotateARL(float x)
    {
        Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
        Gl.glScaled(s2, s2, 1);
        Gl.glRotated(ang2, 0, 0, 1);
        Gl.glTranslatef(dx2, dy2, dz2);
        draw2();
        Gl.glPopMatrix();
        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
        Gl.glScaled(s1, s1, 1);
        Gl.glTranslatef(dx1, dy1, dz1);
        ang1 += x;
        Gl.glRotated(ang1, 0, 0, 1);
        draw1(points1);
        Gl.glPopMatrix();
        
        simpleOpenGlControl1.Invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: You have to set the matrix mode (`Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);`) before you can push the matrix of that mode (`Gl.glPushMatrix();`)

Comment: @Rabbid76 I have changed the position of the strings in all the methods, as you said, but the problem still persists.

Comment: I know this doesn't solve the problem, but it was still wrong.